# Regular Expression to limit text length in Open Office Calc

Tags: regex, openoffice-calc

What is a regular expression compatible with OpenOffice Calc to limit each cell to 30 characters?

Example:

> This is a sample text for my website.

Becomes:

> This is a sample text for my w

Comment: Simple string functions (no regex needed, actually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is in cell A1:

```
=LEFT(A1,30)
```

Documentation is at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#LEFT.